# Association rules with Frequent Pattern Mining

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I want to extract association rules for a set of transaction with following code Spark-Scala:

```
val fpg = new FPGrowth().setMinSupport(minSupport).setNumPartitions(10)
val model = fpg.run(transactions)
model.generateAssociationRules(minConfidence).collect()
```

however the number of products are more than 10K so extracting the rules for all combination is computationally expressive and also I do not need them all. So I want to extract only pair wise:

```
Product 1 ==> Product 2
Product 1 ==> Product 3
Product 3 ==> Product 1
```

and I do not care about other combination such as:

```
[Product 1] ==> [Product 2, Product 3]
[Product 3,Product 1] ==> Product 2
```

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks,
Amir

Comment: BTW, I am doing it in Spark-Scala

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your transactions look more or less like this:

```
val transactions = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  Array("a", "b", "e"),
  Array("c", "b", "e", "f"),
  Array("a", "b", "c"),
  Array("c", "e", "f"),
  Array("d", "e", "f")
))
```

you can try to generate frequent itemsets manually and apply `AssociationRules` directly:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.AssociationRules
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth.FreqItemset

val freqItemsets = transactions
  .flatMap(xs => 
    (xs.combinations(1) ++ xs.combinations(2)).map(x => (x.toList, 1L))
  )
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
  .map{case (xs, cnt) => new FreqItemset(xs.toArray, cnt)}

val ar = new AssociationRules()
  .setMinConfidence(0.8)

val results = ar.run(freqItemsets)
```

Notes:

- unfortunately you'll have to handle filtering by support manually. It can be done by applying filter on `freqItemsets`
- you should consider increasing number of partitions before `flatMap`
- if `freqItemsets` is to large to be handled you can split `freqItemsets` into few steps to mimic actual FP-growth:

  1. generate 1-patterns and filter by support
  2. generate 2-patterns using only frequent patterns from step 1

Comment: Thank you! This is extremely helpful. How can I increase number of partitions?

Comment: `transactions.repartition(some_number)`.